# Swift animation query

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, core-animation, quartz-graphics, skspritenode

I am looking for the following animation:

A circle on the screen expands and covers the whole screen. Then a new screen comes.

I have found that this: https://github.com/rounak/TwitterBirdAnimation/
library does somewhat similar. Instead of that twitter logo, we can use the circle. But, the problem is that before expanding, it contracts a little.

Is there any other method to do this?

Kindly guide me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for something similar to a material design transition. A great place to start might be [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app). It may not necessarily be the most efficient way to go about creating a material design transition, but it's a good place to start.